# Postman Invalid characters in native dialog on Snap

Tags: postman, snap

I have postman desktop issue, when trying to export a collection. How can i fix it?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic

snap    2.60.4+23.10.1
snapd   2.60.4+23.10.1
series  16
ubuntu  23.10
kernel  6.5.0-14-generic
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution? Having same issue here.